# Conditions to check for homomorphism described on generators and relations

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, group-presentation, dihedral-groups

Let $G$ be a group defined by generators and relations, say:

\begin{equation}
G = D_{2n} = \left\langle  s, r\mid s^{2} = 1, r^{n} =1, sr =r^{-1} s \right\rangle 
\end{equation}

And an arbitrary group $H$ (with unit element $e$). Let $f$ be an homomorphism from $G$ to $H$ defined by providing the images of $r$ and $s$ by $f$, and saying that for each element $a, b$ of $D_{2n}$ the images must conform to the homomorphism rule $f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$.

Is this true:

> $f$ is a homomorphism if and only if $\left\lbrace f(s)f(s) = e, f(r)^{n} =e, f(s)f(r) = f(r)^{-1} f(s)\right\rbrace$

The "only if" part of the assertion is trivial by applying the definition of an homomorphism to the relations.

But is the "if" part true ? It seems to me that if all the relations $\left\lbrace f(s)f(s) = e, f(r)^{n} =e, f(s)f(r) = f(r)^{-1} s)\right\rbrace$ are verified, then $f$ is well-defined. If this is not true, could you help me by providing a counter-example, maybe with different $G$, $H$ and $f$ ?

**EDIT**

Taking inspiration from a now deleted comment, I think I can express my question better. If $f$ is a function from $\{r, s\}$ to $G$, consider an hypothetical induced homomorphism $\tilde{f}$ from $G$ to $H$ such that its restriction to $\{r, s\}$ yields the same value than $f$. Then:

\begin{equation}
\tilde{f} \textrm{ exists} \Leftrightarrow \left\lbrace f(s)f(s) = e, f(r)^{n} =e, f(s)f(r) = f(r)^{-1} f(s)\right\rbrace
\end{equation}

It seems easy to prove. For the $\Rightarrow$ part, one can prove the contraposition that if $f$ does not satisfy those conditions, then no homomorphism $\tilde{f}$ can exist as any homomorphism would have to satisfy them. For the $\Leftarrow$ part, the induced homomorphism $\tilde{f}$ can be constructed from the evaluations of $f$ on $\{r, s\}$.

Is the equivalence in this new edited version true, for any $G$ ?

Comment: Please don't edit a question after someone has taken the effort to answer it. Instead you should ask a new question (and link back to this one if you wish).

Comment: The question was very badly worded and led to a discussion in comments. I felt that asking a new one would be a waste of the answerer's time. Besides, I appended information instead of modifying the bulk of the text.

Comment: But I agree that makes for a long and convoluted question. Next time I will post a different question and cross-link them.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't true. Consider the function $f:D_4\to (\mathbb Z,+)$ which sends $sr\mapsto1$ and sends anything else to $0$. This is clearly not a homomorphism since $f(sr)\neq f(s)f(r)=0$, but the conditions are satisfied.

Comment: In my definition, you will first define the images of $s$ and $r$, and for $f(sr)$ you will take $f(s)f(r)$. So if you take $f(s) = 0$ and $f(r) = 0$, $f(sr)$ has to be equal to 0. Sorry if my text is not clear.

Comment: @vkubicki That isn't what your conditions say. If that is your condition, you don't even need the three conditions you've written.

Comment: "the images must conform to the homomorphism rule $()=()()$, isn't this what I mentionned ?

Comment: Ok, that's oddly worded, but if that's what you mean, sure, this is true.

Comment: I am sorry if that is not the best way to put it. My intuition is that if you write any element of $G$ in terms of the generators, you can compute the image by $f$. But, if you have a non-trivial relation in $G$, like $s^2=1$, you must check that $f$ is well-defined and give the same value for $s^2$ and 1. The question is then to know if this is a sufficient condition. I would really like to know the proper way to express this. I do not want to take too much of your time, but would really appreciate any help on this too.

Comment: You don't need to check well-definedness, since you are already assuming that $f$ is a defined morphism. Since you assumed the homomorphism relation $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$, this directly implies that $f$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: I edited my question, I hope it is clearer now.